# Como saber se um determinado valor está dentro de uma tabela especifica

Tags: lua

Quero identificar se  um nome está dentro de uma lista.

```
lista = {"name","name2","name3"}
```

*Em *python* eu poderia fazer `if name in lista:`, porém em *lua* é de outra maneira, a qual não sei como é.

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer uma função pra iterar:

```
function Set (list)
  local set = {}
  for _, l in ipairs(list) do set[l] = true end
  return set
end
```

E usar assim

```
local items = Set { "apple", "orange", "pear", "banana" }

if items["orange"] then
  -- faz algo
end
```

Ou, iterar direto na lista

```
local items = { "apple", "orange", "pear", "banana" }

for _,v in pairs(items) do
  if v == "orange" then
    -- do something
    break
  end
end
```

> Original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/656232/916193

Alternativa, indexando pelos nomes:

```
local items = { apple=true, orange=true, pear=true, banana=true }
if items.apple then
    ...
end
```

> Original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/656257/916193

Comment: Eu estou tentando desenvolver isso:   Crie um pequeno módulo que tenha como objetivo reproduzir os poderes dos cargos staff do jogo.
Moderador - !ban Jogador para aparecer uma textarea preta em sua tela e também matá-lo em todos os mapas. !unban Jogador para desfazer o banimento (efeitos do comando !ban)
Mapcrew - !np mapa para colocar um mapa. Ponto extra para quem fizer um !npp mapa (o mapa atual não será pulado) e !ch Jogador (atribuir shaman no próximo round)
Funcorp - !color Jogador para mudar a cor do nickname do jogador.

Comment: Legal, espero que fique bom! É pra RPG?

Answer (score 0):

Se o objeto em questão é um array e contém apenas valores primitivos, então a função recomendada é:

```lua
local function pertence(nome, array)
    for _, valor in ipairs(array) do
        if nome == valor then return true end
    end

    return false
end

-- teste
local a = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128}
local b = { 'Ana', 'Bia', 'Carla', 'Damares'}

local inner = {1, 2}
local c = { inner, {3, 4}, {5, 6} }

print(pertence(9, a)) -- false
print(pertence(32, a)) -- true
print(pertence('Elena', b)) -- false
print(pertence('Bia', b)) -- true

-- cuidado!
print(pertence({1, 2}, c)) -- false
print(pertence(inner, c)) -- true
```

Note que o iterator **ipairs** apenas varre a tabela de 1 até o seu tamanho.
Caso haja chaves não inteiras, ou chaves numéricas menores que 1, ou ainda buracos na tabela, este método não funciona e é preciso usar **pairs**.

Além disso, a igualdade `nome == valor` pode trazer resultados indesejáveis, caso você tenha tabelas dentro da tabela, pois a comparação é por referência.